# Get Outlook Profile Picture in C# Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am trying to get user outlook profile picture in C# plugin, I could not find the picture stored in user entity, is there any way to get the profile picture by using "CRMServiceClient" ?

[User Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFs59.png)

I tried to check the saved data in the Users entity, but I could not find any pictures stored.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.